# docker-machine with google driver stuck on "Waiting for SSH" while creating machine

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, docker-machine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

OS: Debian Buster

```
$ docker-machine version
docker-machine version 0.13.0, build 9ba6da9
```

I am trying to spin up a machine on GCP using docker-machine and google driver. I have created a service account key, saved it as json and pointed `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable to that file. Then, I ran the following command and got the following output

```
$ docker-machine create --driver google --google-project <my project id> --google-disk-size 20 --google-zone us-east1-d --google-machine-type n1-standard-1 --google-machine-image "coreos-cloud/global/images/coreos-stable-1520-8-0-v20171026" --google-username core --google-use-internal-ip vm-test
Running pre-create checks...
(vm-test) Check that the project exists
(vm-test) Check if the instance already exists
Creating machine...
(vm-test) Generating SSH Key
(vm-test) Creating host...
(vm-test) Opening firewall ports
(vm-test) Creating instance
(vm-test) Waiting for Instance
(vm-test) Uploading SSH Key
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
```

When I checked the instance, I see an SSH key being generated for the user `core` (the one I specified in the create command) and associated to the instance. But, docker-machine is stuck on "Waiting for SSH to be available" and isn't moving forward.

After a while, `docker-machine ls` gives the following output (create is still stuck on Waiting for SSH)

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
vm-test            google   Timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It was because I was using `--google-use-internal-ip` so it tried to connect using internal IP instead of the public NATd one.